# Can I change my XHTML pages to HTML - do i just change the references above the header?

Tags: html, xhtml

When I created the pages on my site i did it based on a free template that was written in XHTML. Therefore all my pages are XHTML.

As I understand it, XHTML is effectively just a stricter version of HTML. Im not a programmer and think a less strict version would be better for me. Besides, it looks like browsers are smart enough to deal with irregularities, so the stricter XHTML doenst seem necesary really.

At the top of my pages i have these references:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Can i just swap these out for plain html references (anyone know the exact text i would need?) or would this cause some unforseen issues?

Most of my files are shtml by the way as i use SSIs.

Answer (score 1):

You can just swap out the DOCTYPE for `<!DOCTYPE html>` (the official HTML 5 doctype), and it should work. HTML5 allows well-formed XML syntax as well as HTML4-style tag soup syntax (where certain tags do not have to be explicitly closed).

The `xmlns` attribute isn't required anymore, but if you leave it, user agents should just ignore it.

On a side note, it is still a good idea to ensure that your HTML is 'correct', because if it isn't, user agents will compensate, and they might not all compensate the same way, so you may see different behavior on different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Different HTML versions are different, and the doctype declaration should reflect the version you use, or intend to use. The reason is that doctype declaration is used by validators to determine which syntax is to be validated against.

If you do not validate, then it does not matter which doctype declaration you use, as long as it is one that triggers “standards mode” in browsers. So why would you change it?

Contrary to popular belief, the doctype declaration does not affect browser behavior, except in the sense that some doctype strings trigger “standards mode”, some trigger “quirks mode”, and some trigger “almost standards mode”, in a fairly complicated manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change it to the HTML 5 doctype and things should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```